# Error: "Cannot use None as a query value" When trying to paginate with ListView in Django

Tags: python, django, django-views

I want to implement pagination in search results. After search I see good result (e.g. http://127.0.0.1:8001/search/?q=mos)

But, when I click **"next"**, I have an error:

> ValueError at /search/, Request URL:  http://127.0.0.1:8001/search/?city=2
>
> Cannot use None as a query value

I think that problem in urls (search_results.html).
How can I fix it?
How can I change:

```
<a href="/search?city={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}">next</a>
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

class City(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    class Meta:
      verbose_name_plural = "cities"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

**views.py**

```
class HomePageView(ListView):
    model = City
    template_name = 'cities/home.html'
    paginate_by = 3
    page_kwarg = 'city'

def city_detail(request, pk):
    city = get_object_or_404(City, pk=pk)
    return render(request, 'cities/city_detail.html', {'city': city})


class SearchResultsView(ListView):
    model = City
    template_name = 'cities/search_results.html'
    paginate_by = 3
    page_kwarg = 'city'

    def get_queryset(self): # new
        query = self.request.GET.get('q')
        object_list = City.objects.filter(
            Q(name__icontains=query) | Q(state__icontains=query)
        )
        return object_list
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('search/', SearchResultsView.as_view(), name='search_results'),
    path('', HomePageView.as_view(), name='home'),
    path('city/<int:pk>/', views.city_detail, name='city_detail'),
]
```

**search_results.html**

```
<ul>
  {% for city in object_list %}
    <li>
      {{ city.name }}, {{ city.state }}
    </li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>

<div class="pagination">
    <span class="page-links">
        {% if page_obj.has_previous %}
            <a href="/search?city={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}">previous</a>
        {% endif %}
            <span class="page-current">
                Page {{ page_obj.number }} of {{ page_obj.paginator.num_pages }}.
            </span>
        {% if page_obj.has_next %}
            <a href="/search?city={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}">next</a>
        {% endif %}
    </span>
</div>
```

**home.html**

```
<form action="{% url 'search_results' %}" method="get">
  <input name="q" type="text" placeholder="Search...">
</form>

<ul>
  {% for city in object_list %}
    <li>
      <h1><a href="{% url 'city_detail' pk=city.pk %}">{{ city.name }}</a></h1>
    </li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Comment: Is it possible that you are trying to get the query param `q` in your search views but are actually calling the endpoint with a `city` query_param when you call the endpoint in your `a href`. 
When you try to get `q` you get None.

Comment: I don't understand, why are you passing page number as pk for city?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You get an error saying **ValueError, query is None** because you do not pass in the query `q` in the href for your `next` and `previous` anchor tags.

Modify search_results.html by defining the `next` and `previous` anchor tags like so:

```
<a href="/search?city={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}&q={{ query }}">next</a>
```

Now open views.py. Inside SearchResultsView, you need to add another key called`query` to your context dictionary. To do so, define a method called 
`get_context_data(self, **kwargs)` inside the SearchResultsView class.

```
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['query'] = self.request.GET.get('q')
        return context
```

With that, `query` will be passed in to the template so that your 
`next` link looks like `http://localhost:8000/search/?city=2&q=a`

Answer (score 1):

**Modify search_results.html**

Change the next & previous page link in your template as given below.

```html
<a href="/search?q={{query}}&city={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}">Previous</a>

<a href="/search?q={{query}}&city={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}">Next</a>
```

**Modify urls.py**

remove "/" from search_results like given below...

```py
path('search', SearchResultsView.as_view(), name='search_results'),
```

Then your search URL will be something like that...

http://localhost:8000/search?q=abcd&city=2